# Project setup for full-stack Ktor + Android

Tags: android, gradle

Currently, I have 2 different gradle-based projects, conveniently named 'frontend' and 'backend', like so:

- **frontend** - Android Compose application, uses Ktor client to communicate with the server
- **backend** - Ktor web server

These two should obviously communicate. Data is sent as JSON through HTTP, however, as both are written in Kotlion and both use Ktor, they both send `@Serializable data class` objects. Currently, I have the data classes defined twice, once for each project, and I have to remember that if I change one, I also have to change the other. Instead, I would like to have a large big gradle project, that contains the two child modules, and a third "common" Kotlin Multiplatfom whose entire purpose is to share the code that should be duplicated (such as data classes).

The problem is that both projects also have their on 'gradle' folder, each with a wrapper with a different version. The android module also has a 'libs.versions.toml' file in the 'gradle' directory.

How should I setup the "outside" `build.gradle.kts`, as well as the 'common' module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar project, and here's how I did it.

To set up a Gradle project with multiple modules that share a common Kotlin Multiplatform module, I'm following these steps:

1. Create a new Gradle project at the root level. This project will contain the two child modules and the common Kotlin Multiplatform module.
2. Define the root-level `settings.gradle.kts` file to include the child modules and the common module:

   ```
   rootProject.name = "my-project"

   include(":backend")
   include(":frontend")
   include(":common")
   ```
3. Define the `build.gradle.kts` file for the root project. This file should apply the `java` and `kotlin` plugins, as well as any other common configuration for the project.
4. Define the `build.gradle.kts` file for the `common` module. This file should apply the `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin and define any shared code that should be used by both the `backend` and `frontend` modules.
5. In each of the `backend` and `frontend` modules, define the `build.gradle.kts` file to apply the `java` and `kotlin` plugins, as well as to include the `common` module as a dependency:

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation(project(":common"))
   }
   ```
6. Move any common code that should be shared into the `common` module. This can include data classes, utility functions, and other shared code.
7. Remove any duplicate code in the `backend` and `frontend` modules and replace it with dependencies on the `common` module.

As for the different Gradle wrapper versions and `libs.versions.toml` files, i can either standardize on a single version for all the projects or use different versions for each project. I choose to use different versions, I can specify the version for each project in their respective `gradle-wrapper.properties` files. Similarly, I can define different versions for each project in their respective `build.gradle.kts` files or use a single version defined in the root-level `build.gradle.kts` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've been tinkering with the build files, plugin versions and all that to make the existing projects work. Any idea how to make the `libs.versions.toml` file work, if placed in a child module's "gradle" directory? Gradle doesn't seem to know it exists unless I place it in the root "gradle" folder.

Comment: I ended up using a single Gradle version, as that worked, but still, any way to move `libs.versions.toml` to the frontend submodule?